# knockoutjs weird html comment binding thing

Tags: knockout.js

```
 <!-- ko foreach: GlobalViewData -->
 <!-- /ko -->
```

The above supposedly comment section in my html page actually kicks knockoutjs foreach binding. I don't know why. But i just realized it does. Someone care to explain why this is happening?

Comment: Many of the knockout bindings allow for [containerless](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-4-using-foreach-without-a-container-element) methods of using them.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-4-using-foreach-without-a-container-element),

The `<!-- ko -->` and `<!-- /ko -->` comments act as start/end markers, defining a “virtual element” that contains the markup inside. Knockout understands this virtual element syntax and binds as if you had a real container element.

Comment: thanks... was too caught up with deadlines... a case of seeing but not seeing :)